# How can I get <p> elements whose <h3> tags enclose the words "Contact:" using scrapy response?

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape only the contact information from a database using scrapy shell:

```
<div class="info-section">
                    <h3>State(s) Served:</h3>
                    <p>Nationwide (US)</p>  </div>
<div class="info-section">
                    <h3>Year Founded:</h3>
                    <p>1985</p>  </div>
                
<div class="info-section">
                    <h3>Description:</h3>
                    <p>Corporate tax accounting/consulting. Specialties:  280E Compliance/Planning, Research & Development Tax Credits, Cost Segregation, IRS Representation, Certified Financial Auditing.</p> </div>
                                    <div class="info-section">
                        <h3>Contact:</h3>
                        <p><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="93f1e1eaf2fdd3f0e3f2fef7bdf0fcfe">[email&#160;protected]</a> | 847-382-1166 X28</p>
                    </div>
```

I selected the info section using `sel = response.css('.info-section')` and then I can iterate over the `p` elements, but how do I chose just the `<h3>` tag that has the contact info and then get the `<p>` text?

Comment: Please paste your python code for more information.

Comment: I was using scrapy shell and just trying to select those elements using response in the cmd line

Comment: your contact info has a class ... you can use that class instead

Answer (score 1):

If you need to take text of `<p>` that is after `<a>` with email, you can try this:

```
>>> txt = """<div class="info-section">
...                     <h3>State(s) Served:</h3>
...                     <p>Nationwide (US)</p>  </div>
... <div class="info-section">
...                     <h3>Year Founded:</h3>
...                     <p>1985</p>  </div>
... 
... <div class="info-section">
...                     <h3>Description:</h3>
...                     <p>Corporate tax accounting/consulting. Specialties:  280E Compliance/Planning, Research & Development Tax Credits, Cost Segregation, IRS Representation, Certified Financial Auditing.</p> </div>
...                                     <div class="info-section">
...                         <h3>Contact:</h3>
...                         <p><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="93f1e1eaf2fdd3f0e3f2fef7bdf0fcfe">[email&#160;protected]</a> | 847-382-1166 X28</p>
...                     </div>"""
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> sel = Selector(text=txt)
>>> sel.xpath('//h3[contains(text(), "Contact")]/following-sibling::p/a/following-sibling::text()').get()
u' | 847-382-1166 X28'
```

Or even shorter, as @Jack Fleeting said:

```
>>> sel.xpath('//h3[contains(text(), "Contact")]/following-sibling::p/text()').get()
u' | 847-382-1166 X28'
```

Comment: In this particular case, can't the xpath expression be a shorter `//h3[contains(text(), "Contact")]/following-sibling::p/text()`?